# How to find the equation of a plane given the equation of a line?

Tags: calculus, vectors

Given the line $(x, y, z) = (1, -3, 2) + t(-2, 4, 7)$ , find planes to satisfy the following condition:

- A plane which is not intersected by the line

I'm just starting to learn this and find it a little confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go through each paragraph of below until you are sure of the answer yourself:

---

First of all, in $\mathbb{R}^3$, what is required for a line and a plane to not intersect? Clearly, if the line and the plane is not parallel, then they *must* intersect at a point. So they better be parallel. So given they are parallel, we want one more condition: the line must not lie on the plane (obviously). Note that, these conditions are satisfied by infinitely many planes.

Now your line has direction vector $(-2,4,7)$. I assume you know how to find the equation of a plane using a vector normal to it. So how do we find a vector normal to $(-2,4,7)$?

Observe: $(-2)\times2+4\times1+7\times0=0$. Hence we see that the vector $(2,1,0)$ is normal to our direction vector (since their scalar product is 0). So we have found a normal vector to our plane.

Finally, we want any plane normal to this vector *not passing through* $(1,-3,2)$, or indeed any point on the line as the line must not lie on the plane. How do we make sure a point is not on the line? Consider a point $(2,-3,2)$. Notice that there is no $t$ satisfying

$ (1,-3,2)+t(-2,4,7)=(2,-3,2)$

(Notice also, that I just added 1 to x component of $(1,-3,2)$ to produce this vector)

So we are done: putting all together, our plane is normal to $(2,1,0)$ and must pass through $(2,-3,2)$, so we have our equation of plane:

$[\vec{r}-(2,-3,2)]\cdot (2,1,0)=0 \implies \vec{r}\cdot(2,1,0)=1 \implies 2x+y=1$

where $\vec{r}=(x,y,z)$

Comment: this was really helpful and detailed!
the only part I'm confused with is where you said "any point on the line as the line must not lie on the plane" but then you went on saying "how do we make sure a point is not on the line?". Wouldn't we want to find the point ON the line that's not (1,-3,2) like your first statement said?

Comment: also, how do you know the plane passes through (2,-3,2)? Is it just because the line does not pass through it, hence the plane can? Does that also mean that point can vary and be just about anything that isn't a scalar multiple of the line or (1, -3, 2)?

Comment: Glad it helped.. as for your first question, at that point we are already given that the plane is parallel to the line. So imagine a plane parallel to the plane. If 'a' point lies both on line and plane, then since the plane and line are parallel, every point of line lies on the plane. So we need to ensure that not a single point on the line lies on the plane. This is guaranteed if the plane passes through some point not on the line since they are parallel. So we need to find a point not on the line, which the plane passes through.

Comment: For second question; yes, we 'must' have our plane go though a point not on the line. This of course means that any point not expressible in the form of (1,-3,2)+t(-2,4,7) will do the job (e.g. (3,-3,2) would have been equally good point). There are infnitely many of them, and this means that there are infinitely many planes which satisfy the conditions (rather obvious if you think about how many planes are parallel to a given line)

Comment: alright I believe I understand it now. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

The equation for a plane can be written as

$$Ax+By+Cz+D=0$$

for some constants $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$.

If the plane intersects the line, then for some $t$, we have

$$A(1-2t)+B(-3+4t)+C(2+7t)+D=0$$

Rearranging the above, we get

$$A-3B+2C+D+t(-2A+4B+7C)=0$$

Solving this for $t$, we get 
$$t=\frac{-A+3B-2C-D}{-2A+4B+7C}$$

Hence we have a solution except possibly when the denominator is equal to $0$, that is $-2A+4B+7C=0$. Additionally, when $-2A+4B+7C=0$, we find solutions in our equation if and only if $A-3B+2C+D=0$ as well (note that in this last case, the equation is $0$ for every $t$, so these are planes in which the line lies).

In conclusion, any plane in the form $Ax+By+Cz+D=0$ does not intersect the line if and only if $-2A+4B+7C=0$ and $A-3B+2C+D\ne 0$

Comment: this was good but my only issue is that I cannot leave A, B, C, D in their variables and just set restrictions. The answer is expect to be in the equation you listed at the beginning, for i.e. 2x+4y+6z+11=0. I'm not the best at explaining but I hope you got a sense of what I mean :)

Comment: @MicMac11 Well, we can just find any set of $A$,$B$,$C$, and $D$ which satisfy these conditions. For example, we could take $A=2$, $B=1$, $C=0$, $D=0$. Then we get $-2A+4B+7C=0$ and $A-3B+2C+D=-1\ne 0$. In fact when we have $A=2$, $B=1$, and $C=0$ we could take $D$ as anything we want as long as $D\ne1$.